# The output in CMD for "results" variable from CromaDB is empty

Tags: python, chromadb

the problem is when i try execute the python file from CMD y get the array empty but if the program is executed in VS Code the answer in the terminal for the variable "results" contain the info for i question for. ids, documents, embeddings is there. however in CMD is not there.
[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nPfD.png)
[CMD outpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cenk1.png)

i tried convert "results" a str but the result was the same

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of code, errors or text. Instead copy the text, paste it in your question (using `edit` button), and then highlight what you pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve line feeds and white space.